# python: how to convert txt data into nestled array list?

Tags: python, arrays

In my Python screen I have atomic coordinates stored as the variable in the following format:

```
ATOM      1  C   LIG    1       77.036  58.294  67.981 -0.14 +0.02    +0.345 C \nATOM      2  O   LIG    1       77.559  57.961  69.048 -0.13 -0.02    -0.247 OA\nATOM      3  O   LIG    1       76.286  59.397  67.781 -0.14 -0.00    -0.462 OA\nATOM      4  C   LIG    1       75.371  59.837  68.775 -0.17 -0.01    +0.232 C \n
```

Here the example for 4 atoms, where each block(atom) is separated by '\n'. From this initial data, XYZ coordinates of each block and store it in a nestled list. For those 4 atoms, the expected results should be:

```
[[77.036, 58.294, 67.981],[77.559,57.961,69.048],[76.286,59.397,67.781],[75.371,59.837,68.775]]
```

Comment: what you've tried so far to get that?

Comment: `[atom.split()[5:8] for atom in data.strip().split('\n')]`?

Comment: sometimes it gives an empty sublists:  ['70.309', '69.845', '67.014'], [], []]

Comment: Then you didn't give a good example of your data. It works on the given example. Please read about [ask] and how to provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex to extract the needed values:

```
import re
data = "ATOM      1  C   LIG    1       77.036  58.294  67.981 -0.14 +0.02    +0.345 C \nATOM      2  O   LIG    1       77.559  57.961  69.048 -0.13 -0.02    -0.247 OA\nATOM      3  O   LIG    1       76.286  59.397  67.781 -0.14 -0.00    -0.462 OA\nATOM      4  C   LIG    1       75.371  59.837  68.775 -0.17 -0.01    +0.232 C \n"

res = []
for line in data.splitlines():
    m = re.search(r'[\W]{7,}([\d .+-]+)[\D]+', line)
    coords = [float(item.strip()) for item in m.groups()[0].split(' ') if item]
    res.append(coords[:3])
print(res)

expectedResult = [
    [77.036, 58.294, 67.981], [77.559, 57.961, 69.048],
    [76.286, 59.397, 67.781], [75.371, 59.837, 68.775]
]
print(res == expectedResult)
```

Out:

```
[[77.036, 58.294, 67.981], [77.559, 57.961, 69.048], [76.286, 59.397, 67.781], [75.371, 59.837, 68.775]]
True
```

Comment: In fact I've already tried to use something like this via RE: 1) I need only 3 first flots from each blog, e.g '77.036', '58.294', '67.981'. The second (and what was so complicated is to obtain all results in the same nestled list and not in the separate lists :-)

Comment: @Hot JAMS: Edited.

Comment: coords = [float(item.strip()) for item in m.groups()[0].split(' ') if item]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Comment: @MauriceMeyer this is not a well-asked question... As a 10k+ user you shouldn't answer it, but rather ask clarifications from the OP

Comment: Maybe you got empty lines in your original data ? The code works with the information you provided!

Comment: allright allright!  thank you very much anyway for your example! :-)